# DAX accounting calculations with dates and amounts in Power BI

Tags: time, dax

I am completely new to DAX and therefore still deep in the process of understanding the logics of this language.

I have a dataset containing of the columns: dates, amounts, events indices, balances and days.

I want to obtain two things:
- the balance at the start of each month
- the difference between all positive and negative amounts (so having the sum of one and the other, 
for convenience)

I believe that a Measure if the way to go to get both quantities.
For the first I thought of creating a new column (just to readily 
visualise the result of my tentative formula).
I came up with the following:

```
Column = IF(
    ListaMovimenti[Index]=1,
    ListaMovimenti[Amount],
    IF(
        AND(
            ListaMovimenti[Day]=1,
            LOOKUPVALUE(ListaMovimenti[Day],ListaMovimenti[Index],ListaMovimenti[Index]+1) <> 1
            ),
        LOOKUPVALUE(ListaMovimenti[Balance], ListaMovimenti[Index], ListaMovimenti[Index]-1),
        0
    )
)
```

This (clearly) works only partially, as shown below
[image]

when the formula finds a new month entry not starting with 1, this breaks down.

For the second task, as well as the first one, I thought of invoking some date handling function.
I feel like implementing some loop when evaluating the measure, but I read that it's not easy to implement them in DAX.

**UPDATE**
I managed the first part using the following code

```
Column = IF(
    ListaMovimenti[Index]=1,
    ListaMovimenti[Amount],
    IF(
        MONTH(ListaMovimenti[Date]) <> MONTH(LOOKUPVALUE(ListaMovimenti[Date],ListaMovimenti[Index],ListaMovimenti[Index]-1)),
        LOOKUPVALUE(ListaMovimenti[Balance], ListaMovimenti[Index], ListaMovimenti[Index]-1),
        0
    )
)
```

However, I'm now struggling to turn this into a Measure as I can't call 
the columns into measures.
I also haven't yet figured out the second part: 
getting per-month sum of positive and negative amounts.

I'm having a really hard time figuring the logic of this *one-line* language syntax, 
so any help is hugely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For summing separately each month, I thought of going back to the query step and adding a surrogate column for each month, displaying only the values of that month and blank otherwise. But I believe there's a cleverer way of achieving this

Comment: I may have solved the second task with the following syntax: `SumNegatives = SUMX(ListaMovimenti, IF(ListaMovimenti[Amount]<0, ListaMovimenti[Amount], BLANK()))`

Comment: You need to add a calendar table to your data model: https://www.excelcampus.com/tables/calendar-table-explained/